# Whose thoughts/words are they?

Tags: word, poetry

I think I made it obvious, though I wanted to be poetic, a bit philosophical, yet simple. =)

To whom do those words belong?

> By the mouths it is spoken
>       For I am horrid, a face shedding awe
>       ***grins***
>       None deals
>       With a buzz of a fly, to ears.
>       In the end all that matters
>       Who remains on top of the stairs!
>
> And do they not know surprisingly ***with a serious face***
>       How to blame another vilifyingly
>       for their gluttony
>       And do they not foul o'er their guilelessness
>       Willingly,
>       By their crooky inspirations
>       By a broken mindset
>       By such pulses macabre of inclinations
>
> Speechless!
>       For how you behave and how you denounce!
>       Blind to see or not so brave!
>
> As my dear Gwyllgi rushes panting
>       Burning the ground with his breath in flames dancing
>       Dancing but ruining all they jitter on
>       When the time arrives sooner than they'd think
>       That there is nothing left on
>       Would they realise the fact
>       They've burnt their existence on their own?
>
> Oh you younglings ***takes a breath*** know not
>       What means calling my name,
>       Yet do they not know the concords,
>       Made in the past, o'er the value most precious
>       That mankind holds?
>
> Such ignorance, ***shakes his head***
>       Such arrogance fed by it.
>
> And in the end, has it not come to the desolate words of nothing
>       Nothingness...
>       The deafening silence
>       Of the darkness.
>       Then appear the cacophonical figures
>       No'ne listens no'ne cares!
>       Speaking loud, unwilling to hear the other
>       However fancying to be minded.
>       ***screams with joy*** Welcome to the pandemonium!
>       Look how they are altering into hollow.
>
> No meaning given to the life
>       By the entire existence of YOUR kind ***points out to you***
>       Orbiting the scraps green and grey
>       Ye twits have no idea what expects you in grave
>
> Halt! Listen!... Hear the whispering
>       ***speaks with a smooth touching voice*** Sweet murmur, brazing softly to the ears
>       Like the stars sparkling sharp but delicately carresing
>       Ought to follow or not to follow?
>       Don't you even think?
>       Not even a single word?
>       You do as it tells just like this?
>
> ***yells in anger in a sudden*** Yet I HOLD the guilt of all those fools!(?)
>       Pursuing blindly, indiscreetly, without a second thought!
>       May the shame it holds be revealed,
>       May the faults they've done be unsealed
>       For I have been the capra to blame
>       Even for the sins
>       Never admitted
>       Ever imagined
>       Neither depicted!
>
> Would the fame still hold my name?
>       Would I be still hearing the flames,
>       As the thunders hurl
>       As the floats sweep
>       As it all collapses at the end?
>
> Argh!
>       May my anger never fade
>       ***calmly*** Withal I feel no fury, but pity.
>       May my will upon humankind never dissolve
>       Though, my taste holds no haste!
>
> But one more thing
>       For I've come to this world
>       For I hold the crown here
>       We shall all see each other
>       in the place I hold dear ***grins and disappears in smoke***

**UPDATE:** **Hint**

> In many cases he is drawn as he has some spikes on his body.

Comment: Please do not edit the poem unless there are spelling errors. Thanks !

Comment: I did correct spelling errors, which you added back in; I also improved the formatting, which you seem to be struggling to duplicate after rolling back to the original.

Comment: I would not consider changing 'In a sudden' into 'suddenly' as a spelling error...

Comment: The phrase "in a sudden" is not valid unless followed by another word. I also corrected "carresing", but I did leave behind a couple of non-words out of respect ("vilifyingly" and "cacophonical"). That's how this site works. Others are capable of and encouraged to improve posts where they see fit as long as it does not interfere with the original intent. Clearly you feel the majority of my changes did do some good, since you are trying to add them back in. Perhaps next time, you should instead look more closely at the edits and address them piecemeal instead of immediately reverting the post.

Comment: By the way, to include characters that would otherwise format the post (\* works in the code block because anything inside is left alone) you need to escape it with a "\" character.

Comment: Cacophonical: https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/cacophonical; and for Vilifying-LY, I was making a silly word just for fun, I am aware that it was not used in this way adding -ly at the end. And with 'in a sudden' I meant 'on a sudden': https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/on_a_sudden . Perhaps also you next time approach with a comment instead of directly editing someone else's work overall something that has been written and owned.

Comment: I know how this site works but it was a poetic piece of text. I apologies that I almost erased all of your changes, but it was because (I admit) I was offended by your modification. Anyway thank you for the tip for the special characters.

Comment: I don't have enough from the poem to specifically connect it to my answer, but it wouldn't have anything to do with your avatar, would it?

Comment: I'd say close enough, but no it's not Hades ^^ Clever though, I had totally forgotten my avatar :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like it could be a poem about the thoughts of somebody who according to some sources has a head which is red in color, a body that is dark brown, large spikes protruding from his shoulders, elbows, knees, wrists fingers and toes.  His nose is unusually large, long, pointed, and curved and his teeth, mouth and lips are locked in an eternal snarl.  His common name is:

> Satan

Comment: Yess that's correct ^^